# Use PowerShell to Group CSV data and export report

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I have already checked the website and tried Google resources, but it seems I'm not on the right track.

I'm having a csv file with multiple headers (reference, date, user, level, date occur, etc) and I'm trying to use PowerShell to group this data from Excel, into a report.

The criteria should be the date, then level, and grouped by User.

I have worked this code so far:

```
$data = "C:\Users\Ao\Desktop\data.csv"

$file = Import-Csv $data

foreach ($line in $file){
  # Save the relevant fields in variables
  $sla            = $line.'SLA Escalation Level'
  $reference      = $line.'Request No.'
  $breach         = $line.'SLA Expected Fix Breach On'
  $description    = $line.'Description'
  $assignee       = $line.'Assignee'
  $priority       = $line.'Priority'
  $status         = $line.'Status'
  $updatedon      = $line.'Updated On'
  $updatedby      = $line.'Updated By'

  Group-Object -Property $assignee, $updatedby
}
```

After running the code, nothing happens, not even an error message.

Could you please guide me in the right direction? I'm not looking for a full script, as I'm also trying to learn the logic way.

Answer (score 1):

After the command `$file = Import-Csv $data`, the variable `$file` is a list of objects representing your csv lines. Each object has properties you can manipulate/filter.

For example, the following command will display only *lines* where `Julien` is the assignee:

```
$file | Where-Object { $_.Assignee -eq 'Julien' }
```

If you want to group *lines* by `Assignee`, you can use the following syntax:

```
$file | Group-Object -Property Assignee
```

Then, you can output filtered/grouped data to other functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried to use the first option, for "Julien", and piped it out to a csv. This worked out good, but also the first line has the next text: "#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject". Unfortunately, If i want to have an export with all the Assignees, I'll have to input manually each one's name.

Comment: Add `-NoTypeInformation` to your `Export-Csv` to remove the header